# Jquery gallery like fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am building my own image gallery, Like `fancybox`.

See: http://snabbdesign.com/stack/stack.html

I am having some problem with fading out and in `#gallery`. Some times the background (`#gallery`) will fade out before the image.

Also some times the `.gallery_image` wont be centered as it should.

Please help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
body{
margin:0;
}
#gallery{
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:fixed;
left:0;
top:0;
background:#000;
opacity:0.95;
display:none;
}
.gallery_image{
width:auto;
height:auto;
position:fixed;
left:0;
top:0;
}
#gallery_left,#gallery_right{
position:fixed;
height:100px;
width:100px;
top:50%;
margin-top:-50px;
background:#f00;
cursor:pointer;
display:none;
}
#gallery_left{
left:0;
}
#gallery_right{
right:0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ji">
<img src="1.png">
<img src="2.png">
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   var $gallery_loaded = false,
      height_of_window = $(window).height(),
      width_of_window = $(window).width(),
      max_height = height_of_window - 100,
      max_width = width_of_window - 100,
      $ji_img = $('#ji img');
   $ji_img.css('cursor', 'pointer');
   $ji_img.click(function () {
      var position_of_image = $(this).index();
      if (!$gallery_loaded) {
         $gallery_loaded = true;
         $('body').append('<div id="gallery"></div>');
         $ji_img.each(function () {
            var big_src = $(this).attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "-big.png";
            $('body').append('<img style="display:none" class="gallery_image" src="' + big_src + '" />');
         }); // end each
         $('.gallery_image').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            height_of_gallery_image = $this.height();
            width_of_gallery_image = $this.width();
            if (width_of_gallery_image >= max_width) {
               $this.css({
                  'max-width': max_width + 'px'
               })
            }
            if (height_of_gallery_image >= max_height) {
               $this.css({
                  'max-height': max_height + 'px'
               })
            }
            margin_top = (height_of_window - $this.height()) / 2;
            margin_left = (width_of_window - $this.width()) / 2;
            $this.css({
               'margin-top': margin_top + 'px',
               'margin-left': margin_left + 'px'
            })
         }); // end each
         $('body').append('<div id="gallery_left"></div><div id="gallery_right"></div>');
      } //end if gallery_loaded
      $('#gallery').fadeIn(500);
      $('#gallery_left,#gallery_right').delay(1000).fadeIn(500);
      $('.gallery_image').eq(position_of_image).delay(500).fadeIn(500)
      $('#gallery').click(function () {
         $('.gallery_image').fadeOut(500)
         $('#gallery_left,#gallery_right').fadeOut(500);
         $('#gallery').delay(500).fadeOut(500);
      });
   }); // end click function
}); // end document redy
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try dubble clicking on the images. And then click normal a few times...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) this doesn't happen for me, but if it does I would suggest you have a look at [.queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)

2) use .outerHeight() and .outerWidth() instead .height() and .width()

Comment: Thanks redmoon7777, Why use outerHeight()?

Comment: because it return the "right" height including margins, paddings, borders.. you can read more about it here.    http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/